# Unauthorized error using Terraform to deploy app service on Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a windows container on azure app service with Terraform. The app service plan deploys fine, but I get an authorization error when the app service tries to deploy. I am using connection strings for an ACR instance with the admin user and password. Does anyone have some ideas?

The deployment works if I do it manually from the portal.

```
# Create an App Service Plan with Windows
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "appserviceplan" {
  name                = "${var.rg-name}-plan"
  location            = "westus"
  resource_group_name = var.rg-name

  # Define Windows as Host OS
  kind                = "xenon"
  is_xenon            = true

  # Choose size
  sku {
    tier = "PremiumContainer"
    size = "PC2"
  }
}

# Create an Azure Web App for Containers in that App Service Plan
resource "azurerm_app_service" "dockerapp" {
  name                = "${var.rg-name}-dockerapp"
  location            = "westus"
  resource_group_name = "${var.rg-name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan.id}"

  # Configure Docker Image to load on start
  site_config {
    windows_fx_version = "DOCKER|apps.azurecr.io/test/container:latest"
  }
  app_settings = {
    # Settings for private Container Registires  
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL      = "repo.azureco.io",
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME = "admin user",
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = "password"
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Error creating App Service "dockerapp" (Resource Group "resource-group"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=401 -- Original Error: Code="Unauthorized" Message="Access is denied. Not authorized. latest" Details=[{"Message":"Access is denied. Not authorized. latest"},{"Code":"Unauthorized"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"Unauthorized","ExtendedCode":"01001","Message":"Access is denied. Not authorized. latest","MessageTemplate":"Access is denied.","Parameters":[]}}]
```

Comment: the obvious question would be - you sure you are using the same account in terraform and on the portal? or try clearing you terraform credentials and log into azure again

Answer (score 1):

You could verify if the value of `DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL` is correct, it should be a valid **URL**.

For example, It will look like this in your code.

```
app_settings = {
    # Settings for private Container Registires  
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL      = "https://apps.azurecr.io", 
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME = "admin user",
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = "password"
  }
```

For more references, [Here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/examples/app-service/windows-container/main.tf) is an example of deploying a windows container on azure app service with Terraform.

Comment: Have you verified it? You also need to notice that you have typed the correct credentials for your ACR.

Comment: I have not, but the solution you provided is the same way I go about it in my working projects and see no reason to expand on your answer ot try to steal the spot from you. I believe OP will have his problems solved should they use it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you quickly check if the URL in *DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL* is the same as you are using in *site_config.windows_fx_version*